# How to use jest.spyOn for a function (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

How do I write a test for this function? I first tried to include an optional param in the function such as `mockData` and go from there, but that seems too tedious. I have a function, something like this:

```
export async function getBreadcrumbs(service, id) {
  const { folderId, label } = await getFileDetailsById(id);
  const { breadcrumbs } = await getFoldersService(service, folderId);
  return [...breadcrumbs, { label, id: '' }];
  }
```

I'm thinking `jest.spyOn` is what I need to write the test with but I'm not sure how to approach it. I started with:

```
import * as crumbs from '.....data'

describe('getCrumbs', () => {
    it('should return breadcrumbs name and id', async () => {
      const data = jest.spyOn(crumbs, 'getBreadcrumbs')
    });
});
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here. How can I mock a return of this function? This function returns:

```
[{ displayName: 'Hey', id: '' }]
```

`getFileDetailsById` and `getFoldersService` are API calls.

TLDR: I have a function and I'm unsure how to mock its return.

Comment: A spy is a mock; the same "return this value" mechanisms apply. But you're *spying*, not mocking, and testing `getBreadcrumbs`, not something that uses it--you'd mock `getBreadcrumbs`' API calls.

Comment: Testing `getBreadcrumbs` means testing all behavior: did it make its API calls?  Did it return the correct results based on the combination of API call results? You'd mock `getBreadcrumbs` return value if you're testing something that **uses** it.

Comment: Right I understand that, I need to test everything inside getBreadcrumbs. I'm unsure of how to write that out by mocking it (I've never used Jest).

Comment: You don't mock the function you're testing--you want to test the function, not its mock. The functions it **uses** should be mocked (it's sometimes easier to mock the HTTP requests (with the set of tradeoffs that comes with that) when code has hard dependencies like `getBreadcrumbs`, but it's often preference and actual requirements that determine this).

Comment: Test main function getBreadcrumbs, but mock the functions it uses (inside, IE: getFiledDetailsById, getFoldersService). Is that correct?

Comment: Testing `getBreadcrumbs` means testing the returned array. `getBreadcrumbs` uses data from `getFileDetailsById`, which feeds `getFoldersService`. There's no way to know if `getBreadcrumbs` **works** unless `label` and `breadcrumbs` are known . Since the API calls are hardcoded *(as opposed to injected/looked up)* you can either mock their module(s) or mock how they work (e.g., by intercepting their HTTP requests).

Comment: Yeah so that helps with what I need to do, but I'm still unsure how to write this out.

Comment: You'll need to see how to either mock the module(s) w/ the two API calls or mock the HTTP requests; which makes the most sense can depend. Mocking exported module functions can get a bit tricky to think about because load order matters.